# How to collapse mobile menu after an anchor link click?

Tags: jquery, mobile, menu, anchor

I'm designing a single paged website in wordpress and i got stuck. Mobile menu won't collapse after link click. I think i need to add script to footer but I'm not able to write it correctly. I've been trying to watch youtube for jQuery basics and searched web for similar issues. I understand it theoretically but I'm not successful to write the script exactly for my website.

This is the website: [http://www.apollokemp.cz/](http://apollokemp.cz)

I'm trying to achieve to collapse menu as fast as it opens after clicking any link in mobile menu.

I understand that everybody has his own hard work but maybe there is someone who will find out this too easy and share me solution.

Thanks. Wish you good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add this jQuery to a `<script>` tag on your page to add this functionality.

It will wait for the mobile navigation to be created (which happens the first time your mobile menu button is clicked), then set up a listener for `click` events on the links in your mobile navigation - then it will "click" on the close button of your mobile menu for you when you click a menu link.

```js
jQuery('.mobilenav-main-link').on('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('.mobilenav-main-link').off();
    jQuery('.mobile-nav-frame ul a').on('click', function() {
      jQuery('.mobile-nav-frame .close').trigger('click');
    });
  }, 100);
});
```